# Choosing a random flat color

Tags: array, ios, cache, swift

I have a big array of custom flat colors with perhaps 100 lines:

```
extension UIColor {

class func randomFlatColor() -> UIColor {

    let colors = [
                    UIColor(red: 210/255, green: 77/255,  blue: 87/255,  alpha: 1.0),
                    UIColor(red: 217/255, green: 30/255,  blue: 24/255,  alpha: 1.0),
                    UIColor(red: 150/255, green: 40/255,  blue: 27/255,  alpha: 1.0),
                    UIColor(red: 220/255, green: 198/255, blue: 224/255, alpha: 1.0),
                    UIColor(red: 103/255, green: 65/255,  blue: 114/255, alpha: 1.0),
                    UIColor(red: 68/255,  green: 108/255, blue: 179/255, alpha: 1.0),
                    UIColor(red: 210/255, green: 77/255,  blue: 87/255,  alpha: 1.0),
                    UIColor(red: 228/255, green: 241/255, blue: 254/255, alpha: 1.0),
                    UIColor(red: 65/255,  green: 131/255, blue: 215/255, alpha: 1.0),
                    UIColor(red: 89/255,  green: 171/255, blue: 227/255, alpha: 1.0),
                    UIColor(red: 129/255, green: 207/255, blue: 224/255, alpha: 1.0),
                    UIColor(red: 82/255,  green: 179/255, blue: 217/255, alpha: 1.0),
                    UIColor(red: 197/255, green: 239/255, blue: 247/255, alpha: 1.0),
                    UIColor(red: 34/255,  green: 167/255, blue: 240/255, alpha: 1.0),
                    UIColor(red: 52/255,  green: 152/255, blue: 219/255, alpha: 1.0),
                    UIColor(red: 44/255,  green: 62/255,  blue: 80/255,  alpha: 1.0),
                    UIColor(red: 25/255,  green: 181/255, blue: 254/255, alpha: 1.0),
                    UIColor(red: 51/255,  green: 110/255, blue: 123/255, alpha: 1.0),
                    UIColor(red: 34/255,  green: 49/255,  blue: 63/255,  alpha: 1.0),
                    UIColor(red: 30/255,  green: 139/255, blue: 195/255, alpha: 1.0),
                    UIColor(red: 58/255,  green: 83/255,  blue: 155/255, alpha: 1.0),
                    UIColor(red: 52/255,  green: 73/255,  blue: 94/255,  alpha: 1.0),
                    UIColor(red: 103/255, green: 128/255, blue: 159/255, alpha: 1.0),
                    UIColor(red: 37/255,  green: 116/255, blue: 169/255, alpha: 1.0),
                    UIColor(red: 31/255,  green: 58/255,  blue: 147/255, alpha: 1.0),
                    UIColor(red: 137/255, green: 196/255, blue: 244/255, alpha: 1.0),
                    UIColor(red: 75/255,  green: 119/255, blue: 190/255, alpha: 1.0),
                    UIColor(red: 92/255,  green: 151/255, blue: 191/255, alpha: 1.0),
                    UIColor(red: 78/255,  green: 205/255, blue: 196/255, alpha: 1.0),
                    UIColor(red: 162/255, green: 222/255, blue: 208/255, alpha: 1.0),
                    UIColor(red: 135/255, green: 211/255, blue: 124/255, alpha: 1.0),
                    UIColor(red: 144/255, green: 198/255, blue: 149/255, alpha: 1.0),
                    UIColor(red: 38/255,  green: 166/255, blue: 91/255,  alpha: 1.0),
                    UIColor(red: 3/255,   green: 201/255, blue: 169/255, alpha: 1.0),
                    UIColor(red: 104/255, green: 195/255, blue: 163/255, alpha: 1.0),
                    UIColor(red: 101/255, green: 198/255, blue: 187/255, alpha: 1.0),
                    UIColor(red: 27/255,  green: 188/255, blue: 155/255, alpha: 1.0),
                    UIColor(red: 27/255,  green: 163/255, blue: 156/255, alpha: 1.0),
                    UIColor(red: 102/255, green: 204/255, blue: 153/255, alpha: 1.0),
                    UIColor(red: 54/255,  green: 215/255, blue: 183/255, alpha: 1.0),
                    UIColor(red: 200/255, green: 247/255, blue: 197/255, alpha: 1.0),
                    UIColor(red: 134/255, green: 226/255, blue: 213/255, alpha: 1.0),
                    UIColor(red: 46/255,  green: 204/255, blue: 113/255, alpha: 1.0),
                    UIColor(red: 22/255,  green: 160/255, blue: 133/255, alpha: 1.0),
                    UIColor(red: 63/255,  green: 195/255, blue: 128/255, alpha: 1.0),
                    UIColor(red: 1/255,   green: 152/255, blue: 117/255, alpha: 1.0),
                    UIColor(red: 3/255,   green: 166/255, blue: 120/255, alpha: 1.0),
                    UIColor(red: 77/255,  green: 175/255, blue: 124/255, alpha: 1.0),
                    UIColor(red: 42/255,  green: 187/255, blue: 155/255, alpha: 1.0),
                    UIColor(red: 0/255,   green: 177/255, blue: 106/255, alpha: 1.0),
                    UIColor(red: 30/255,  green: 130/255, blue: 76/255,  alpha: 1.0),
                    UIColor(red: 4/255,   green: 147/255, blue: 114/255, alpha: 1.0),
                    UIColor(red: 38/255,  green: 194/255, blue: 129/255, alpha: 1.0),
                    UIColor(red: 253/255, green: 227/255, blue: 167/255, alpha: 1.0),
                    UIColor(red: 248/255, green: 148/255, blue: 6/255,   alpha: 1.0),
                    UIColor(red: 235/255, green: 149/255, blue: 50/255,  alpha: 1.0),
                    UIColor(red: 232/255, green: 126/255, blue: 4/255,   alpha: 1.0),
                    UIColor(red: 244/255, green: 178/255, blue: 80/255,  alpha: 1.0),
                    UIColor(red: 242/255, green: 120/255, blue: 75/255,  alpha: 1.0),
                    UIColor(red: 235/255, green: 151/255, blue: 78/255,  alpha: 1.0),
                    UIColor(red: 254/255, green: 171/255, blue: 53/255,  alpha: 1.0),
                    UIColor(red: 211/255, green: 84/255,  blue: 0/255,   alpha: 1.0),
                    UIColor(red: 243/255, green: 156/255, blue: 18/255,  alpha: 1.0),
                    UIColor(red: 249/255, green: 105/255, blue: 14/255,  alpha: 1.0),
                    UIColor(red: 249/255, green: 191/255, blue: 59/255,  alpha: 1.0),
                    UIColor(red: 242/255, green: 121/255, blue: 53/255,  alpha: 1.0),
                    UIColor(red: 230/255, green: 126/255, blue: 34/255,  alpha: 1.0),
                    UIColor(red: 236/255, green: 236/255, blue: 236/255, alpha: 1.0),
                    UIColor(red: 108/255, green: 122/255, blue: 137/255, alpha: 1.0),
                    UIColor(red: 210/255, green: 215/255, blue: 211/255, alpha: 1.0),
                    UIColor(red: 238/255, green: 238/255, blue: 238/255, alpha: 1.0),
                    UIColor(red: 189/255, green: 195/255, blue: 199/255, alpha: 1.0),
                    UIColor(red: 236/255, green: 240/255, blue: 241/255, alpha: 1.0),
                    UIColor(red: 149/255, green: 165/255, blue: 166/255, alpha: 1.0),
                    UIColor(red: 218/255, green: 223/255, blue: 225/255, alpha: 1.0),
                    UIColor(red: 171/255, green: 183/255, blue: 183/255, alpha: 1.0),
                    UIColor(red: 242/255, green: 241/255, blue: 239/255, alpha: 1.0),
                    UIColor(red: 191/255, green: 191/255, blue: 191/255, alpha: 1.0)
                ]()

    return colors[arc4random_uniform(UInt32(colors.count))]
}
```

How can I optimize this? That's not only colors, but also division operations. Would replacing the division by directly the float value?

Comment: What sort of optimization do you want to do?  Do you want to make it fast to instantiate?  Or do you want to make it optimally readable for the programmer...because this isn't very readable...

Comment: I think there's nothing special to read there ^^
And yes fast to instantiate because this method can be called a few times ( like 7-8 )

Comment: Ho I thought about an array of tuple(r, g, b) maybe ?

Comment: This can definitely be made more efficient, but have you actually timed it using Instruments to see how fast/slow it runs?

Comment: I'm not yet familiar with Instruments. Which one you suggest me ? The Activity Indicator ?
Maybe Unit Test ?
Or even doing it in background ?

Comment: There is an instrument called "Time Profiler".

Comment: Random colors will probably look terrible. Why not use HSV instead of RGB? This can easily be converted to Swift. http://martin.ankerl.com/2009/12/09/how-to-create-random-colors-programmatically

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[This StackOverflow question can solve part of your problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25354882/static-function-variables-in-swift).  Setting up the array as a static variable within the function will mean it is only initialized once and any future call to the function will only have to calculate the random index to pull from and return whatever color object is at that index.

And while this solution should be an improvement from the perspective of time, it would mean you're app is constantly consuming a larger amount of memory (versus just temporarily consuming this memory while this function is calculating).

Your tuple idea in the comments is a better way to go.

```
typealias ColorTuple = (red: CGFloat, green: CGFloat, blue: CGFloat, alpha: CGFloat)

extension UIColor {
    class func randomFlatColor() -> UIColor {
        struct RandomColors {
            static let colors: Array<ColorTuple> = [
                (red: 1.0, green: 0.0, blue: 0.0, alpha: 1.0),  // red
                (red: 0.0, green: 1.0, blue: 0.0, alpha: 1.0),  // green
                (red: 0.0, green: 0.0, blue: 1.0, alpha: 1.0)   // blue
                // etc...
            ]
        }

        let colorCount = UInt32(RandomColors.colors.count)
        let randomIndex = arc4random_uniform(colorCount)
        let color = RandomColors.colors[Int(randomIndex)]

        return UIColor(red: color.red, green: color.green, blue: color.blue, alpha: color.alpha)
    }
}
```

Initializing the array of tuples should be slightly faster than initializing the array of `UIColor` objects.  But importantly, it should take significantly less memory to keep this array around, and using this pattern, the array will only have to be initialized once.